# PL/SQL DBMS_XMLQUERY max size

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database

My oracle version is 11g release 2

Our system is using DBMS_XMLQUERY to transform sql result into xml, but recently the data is becoming large and we get this error: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`

The reason seems to be DBMS_XMLQUERY cannot handle too many records, but [oracle's official document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xmlque.htm) doesn't show the limitation. So maybe I have done something wrong. You can reproduce the problem in the following steps:

step1:

> create table XMLDATA (    data_id int primary key,    data_str
>   VARCHAR2(100) );

step2:

```
INSERT INTO XMLDATA values(1, 'test0123456789');
INSERT INTO XMLDATA values(2, 'test0123456789');
INSERT INTO XMLDATA values(3, 'test0123456789');
....
INSERT INTO XMLDATA values(500, 'test0123456789');
```

step3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
function test(total in int) return clob is
i int;
vn_ctx              DBMS_XMLQUERY.ctxHandle;
BEGIN
    vn_ctx := DBMS_XMLQUERY.NEWCONTEXT('select data_id, data_str from XMLDATA where rownum <= ' || total);
    DBMS_XMLQuery.propagateOriginalException(vn_ctx,true);
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.useNullAttributeIndicator(vn_ctx,true); 
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETROWTAG(vn_ctx, 'ITEM');
    DBMS_XMLQUERY.SETROWSETTAG(vn_ctx, 'PODATA');
    return DBMS_XMLQUERY.GETXML(vn_ctx);
END;
```

step4:

execute function test with a number greater than 400. Then you'll get 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error'

thanks in advance

**EDIT**

**Really sorry... I got the old code, someone adds a log statement without noticing me. The log statement can only accept a maximum of 32767 characters in one line, so the error is raised. The above function is executed by a debug tool, which gives the same error, so it's the tool's problem, not oracle.**

**Thanks for your answering and sorry for my naive mistakes...**

Comment: I'm quite sure that the record count is not the problem. How you are executing the function?Please also paste full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

I get no errors if the variable to hold the return value is big enough.

```
declare 
  rv1 clob;
  rv2 varchar2(32000); 
begin
  rv1 := test(400);    -- No error
  rv2 := test(200);    -- No error - returned XML is < 32000 in length.
  rv2 := test(400);    -- ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error' 
end;
```